# Getting dependencies using static members in protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, dependencies

I want to implement a simple way of getting dependencies in Swift without the overload of using any dependency injection framework. In order to accomplish this, I have my protocol `Persistence`, its implementation `UserDefaultsPersistence`, and an extension of `Persistence` that adds a static property to the protocol for retrieving an instance of it.

The whole code looks like this:

```
protocol Persistence {
    func getUserToken () -> String?

    func setUserToken(token: String)        
}

extension Persistence {
    static var sharedInstance: Persistence {            
        return UserDefaultsPersistence.sharedInstance
    }
}

class UserDefaultsPersistence : Persistence {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let tokenKey = "token"

    static let sharedInstance: UserDefaultsPersistence = UserDefaultsPersistence()

    private init() { }

    func getUserToken() -> String? {
        return userDefaults.value(forKey: tokenKey) as? String
    }

    func setUserToken(token: String) {
        userDefaults.set(token, forKey: tokenKey)
    }
}
```

This code compiles without problems, however, when I tried to access `Persistence.sharedInstance` I got a compilation error saying that I can't access this field directly from the protocol.

I know that if my protocol had other static members and the `sharedInstance` access any of them, then the compiler can't know what to do, but in the present case this isn't a problem.

Is there any way in which I can annotate the property in order to achieve what I want? Maybe some workaround?

Comment: why dont you declare 'sharedInstance' in protocol? am i missing something? If im not mistaken, you cant add methods to protocol via extension

Comment: @user1244109 The idea here is to be able to manage dependencies using the protocol extensions. If you have a framework that exports a protocol, then in your code your should be able to add a extension to it indicating the class that implement the protocol. In this way you can get ride of external mechanisms

Comment: ok, i see. altho imo this is pretty common situation; which ofcourse is solved by either declaring child protocol with new method, or a class, depending on the situation. "dependency injection" is unpleasant consequence - but it shouts explicitely about the addition, which makes a lot of sense to me.